# How can I duplicate a row right below where it is on DataTables?

Tags: datatables

I found that DataTables now supports colspan and rowspan. but to use it better, I needed to duplicate same data thrice. What I need to make is something as image below, and I can't find whether DataTables supports splitting a row into multiple rows.

[image]

The image shows how I modify each set of data. It means, there will be 5 columns for each data, and it will be split into 3 lines.

Even the question was about duplicating, if there's other way to make a row/set of row for each data with same shape as image, than please explain.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found very wierd trick.
I just made display:none to original table, and only showed child row table.
Not like original table, child row was free to custom the format.
[image]
The answer of other question on the link was useful.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/72745607/10780764